# Bitmap size exceeds 32bits when create bitamp from view

Tags: android, bitmap

Convert view to bitmap and get error on create Bitmap function like this bitmap size exceeds 32bits.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you you use search? There're lots of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008386/android-bitmap-size-exceeds-32-bit-in-dialogfragment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969579/bitmap-size-exceeds-32bits, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370145/mysterious-stacktrace-in-android-developer-console-bitmap-size-exceeds-32bits